# Android JSON unable to connect server by using volley

Tags: java, android, json

The application was design to do quizzes in local network,but i was stuck at android JSON problem,the code was unable to connect and get jsonarray from my server.

In quiz.java,the function JsonObjectRquest was no running,the application only show the message toast"end jsonobject" which i code it at the end of the java function.

It will be very thankful for who help me take a look for the code, also thanks for who found out what was the missing part or bug in the java function.
this is also my first android application.

quiz.java

```
    package com.example.fei.localquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue requestQueue;

TextView ques_id;
TextView title;
TextView answer;
TextView question;
RadioButton ans1;
RadioButton ans2;
RadioButton ans3;
RadioButton ans4;
Button next;
Button prev;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ssss);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass"));

    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
    ans1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    ans2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    ans3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    ans4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextquiz);
    prev= (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousquiz);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);



    questionGET();


}

public void questionGET(){
    //get address from qrcode
    String url = (getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass"));


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(quiz.this,"before loop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("quiz");

                        for (final int[] i = {0}; i[0] <jsonArray.length();) {
                            JSONObject _quiz = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i[0]);
                            String title_id = _quiz.getString("title_id");
                            String question_id = _quiz.getString("question_id");
                            String ans = _quiz.getString("answer");
                            String q1 = _quiz.getString("question");
                            String a1 = _quiz.getString("answer1");
                            String a2 = _quiz.getString("answer2");
                            String a3 = _quiz.getString("answer3");
                            String a4 = _quiz.getString("answer4");

                            title.append(title_id);
                            ques_id.append(question_id);
                            question.append(q1);
                            ans1.append(a1);
                            ans2.append(a2);
                            ans3.append(a3);
                            ans4.append(a4);
                            answer.append(ans);


                            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    i[0]++;
                                    Toast.makeText(quiz.this,i[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });


                        }




                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(quiz.this,"fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR");
                }
            }


    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    Toast.makeText(quiz.this,"end jsonobject",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

}
```

activity_quiz.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fei.localquiz.quiz"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ssss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quiz_question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/question"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previousquiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nextquiz"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nextquiz"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextquiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:text="@string/answer_one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer_two"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer_three"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer_four"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/radioButton3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton3"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
</RadioGroup>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

JSON array result generate by server

```
{"quiz":[{"title_id":"2","question_id":"23","question":"huikmnbghj","answer":"answer2","answer1":"nbghyjn","answer2":"bhyujn","answer3":"bghj","answer4":"nbvghy"},{"title_id":"2","question_id":"25","question":"lk78","answer":"answer2","answer1":"i7uu7","answer2":"uihui","answer3":"hui","answer4":"hui"},{"title_id":"2","question_id":"28","question":"lojmn","answer":"answer3","answer1":"i0ik","answer2":"mnik","answer3":"l,op","answer4":"09"},{"title_id":"2","question_id":"29","question":"123456789o0pwertybn","answer":"answer3","answer1":"nk","answer2":"mk,m","answer3":",m ","answer4":", "}]}
```

Comment: post the error log here

Comment: check the logcat you are getting some error

Comment: there was no error log,it just pass by my JsonObectRequest and toast the message that i declare at end of the JsonObectRquest function.

Comment: i try again on it

Comment: if you don't mind, can your URL or put breakpoint in debugging your code

Comment: NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 192.168.0.13/connectJson.php

Comment: i just using logcat and found this

Comment: can you put `http://` in your URL and try with `http://192.168.0.13/connectJson.php`

Comment: now the url was accessible

Comment: did it worked now?

Comment: but other error was occur FATAL EXCEPTION: main
and
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: check my answer i have updated your JSON parsing code in my answer

Comment: thx a lot!!!my code are working now.

Comment: your most welcome <3 mate

Comment: voted,maybe my account are still new

Comment: ok thank you so much for accepting my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of URL is not found you need to add `http://`
in your URL and try with this URL

```
http://192.168.0.13/connectJson.php
```

Hope this will resolve your problem

**Edit**

Parse your JSON like this

```
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("quiz");
    for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length();i++) {
        JSONObject _quiz = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String title_id = _quiz.getString("title_id");
        String question_id = _quiz.getString("question_id");
        String ans = _quiz.getString("answer");
        String q1 = _quiz.getString("question");
        String a1 = _quiz.getString("answer1");
        String a2 = _quiz.getString("answer2");
        String a3 = _quiz.getString("answer3");
        String a4 = _quiz.getString("answer4");

        title.append(title_id);
        ques_id.append(question_id);
        question.append(q1);
        ans1.append(a1);
        ans2.append(a2);
        ans3.append(a3);
        ans4.append(a4);
        answer.append(ans);
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit 2**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main and java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke

You are getting this error because of you initialize your XML field,

```
TextView ques_id;
TextView title;
TextView answer;
```